# Excel Macro to apply conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

This is my first Macro project and I am trying to figure it out how to fix it.
I want to have yellow highlighted to the same column in range but after run highlighted all in range. Any insight for me?

this is how I want to see.

[image]

This is what happened.

[image]

This is the coding I copied from

https://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-macro-to-apply-conditional-formatting-based-on-value/

and then modified it.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition
    Set rg = Range("$C$4:$AG$14")

    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete

    'define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "weekday(C$5)=7")
    Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "weekday(C$5)=1")


    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
        rg.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        rg.Font.Color = vbBlack
    End With

    With cond2
        rg.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        rg.Font.Color = vbBlack
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the `Type` argument to `xlExpression`.
2. In your `With` statements, you should remove `rg`. What you are doing is applying the formatting onto the range (`rg`) itself, not on the `FormatCondition` object (`cond1`/`cond2`).

```
Sub test()

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition
    Set rg = Range("$C$4:$AG$14")

    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete

    'define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, "=WEEKDAY(C$5)=7")
    Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, "=WEEKDAY(C$5)=1")


    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
    End With

    With cond2
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If an answer resolves your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick beside the answer. (You can only accept one answer if there are multiple answers submitted). @DEEK

Comment: I accepted it. I just start stackflow and I did not know it. Thanks again Raymond. Have a great day.